# Drag'n Drop with file downloading C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, download

I got a problem. I'd like to drag'n drop a file from my Form to explorer/ the desktop.

The problem is that the file is online. Then it must be downloaded somewhere on the disk before being copied in the destination folder.

I created a shell extension (I think it's that, at any rate), who use a background worker to download the file, but of course, even with that, while the file is downloading, the drag and drop operation isn't over and the UI is freezing.

What I would like to do is just doing a drag and drop to explorer, which will launch a download and copy the file, without the UI freezing during the download.

So, what can I do ?

Could I get the destination path and do the copying myself ?

Could I launch the entire drag and drop operation in another thread ?

I searched for a while and couldn't find any clear answers.

Comment: Is the file represented in an embedded webbrowser, or are you responsible for showing the file?

Comment: I'm responsible for showing it. In a ListView, to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Make a complete logical separation of those two concerns:  drag & drop versus the actual download/save of the file.

Handle the drag & drop operation in its entirety, and upon completion (typically in an `OnDragDrop` method), start the download and save process.  You'd likely want an indication of progress somewhere.

Attempting to do it all *during* the drag/drop operation seems doomed to fail.  You will never know just how long the download might take, or if it will fail entirely.  Handling any of that in the midst of a drag & drop seems bad.

Comment: This is what I want to do, but it's not as simple as it seems (at least for me ...). If I do dragdrop operation, I share a IDataObject with explorer. Explorer will call "GetData", and do the copying (or whatever I tell it to do). The Drag'nDrop operation is over when explorer is done with this GetData(), and my application don't get any data from it. Then, how can I launch a download at this moment and put the file into the right directory when I don't even know which one is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a [BackgroundWorkder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) inside the drop event handler.